# what happens when you load a directory?

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

I am trying to learn some simple matlab code posted by my professor, and the first line goes somehting like

```
load /class/mat121/lab1/data
```

I've never seen "load" used like this before, what does it do? does it load all .m files in the directory?

I also see a lot of custom functions in the code, such as "T()", "Lon()", "Lat()" etc, they aren't standard matlab functions therefore I am assuming they are imported from that directory?

thanks

Comment: Please split multiple questions in different questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Title is incorrect, because "data" is not directory.

You can refer to [load](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) function.

Anyway,

```
/class/mat121/lab1/
```

this should be the directory path

```
data
```

this should be a file called "data.mat" which contains matlab workspace variable that is previously saved with [save](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html) function.

---

So,

```
load /class/mat121/lab1/data
```

loads workspace variables from "data.mat" which is located under "/class/mat121/lab1/".

Comment: @EwynnTomato is correct. `load()` is for retrieving MATLAB-formatted data from a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to matlab, the best thing to do would be to run the following commands and have a look at the results:

```
help load
help which
which T
help T
which Lon
which Lat
```

Running these commands should tell you:

1. What Load does
2. What which does
3. Where T is
4. What T does
5. Where Lon is
6. Where Lat is